# Im getting a 404 error after submitting my jsp page

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jdbc

After I fill out the form and submit it I get a 404 error.  I want the table of the submitted data to appear after hitting the submit button.  I'm also finding that my submission is not recording in the database and I'm not sure why?

ERROR:HTTP Status 404 - /Lab5/ShowParameters
Im using Tomcat 8.0.24

**DBentry.java**

```
package db;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

//import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
//import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class DBentry {
    static DBentry instance = new DBentry();
    Connection dbconn;
    ResultSet results = null;
    java.sql.PreparedStatement sql;
    String dpwd = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;

    //change URL to your database server as needed
    String dbPath="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/cs485_lab5";

    public static DBentry getInstance() {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = new DBentry();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Establish connection to MySQL server
    public Connection newConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            try {           
                dbconn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbPath,"root","root");
                System.out.println("gain the connection");
                return dbconn;
            }
            catch (Exception s){
                System.out.println(s.getStackTrace().toString());}
        }
        catch (Exception err){
            System.out.println(err.getStackTrace().toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public ResultSet selectStatement( String query ) {
        try {

            dbconn=instance.newConnection();
            sql= dbconn.prepareStatement(query);
            ResultSet results;
            results=sql.executeQuery();
            System.out.println("query="+query);


            //WARNING!
            //Need to process ResultSet before closing connection
            dbconn.close();
            return results;
        }
        catch (Exception err) {
            System.out.println(err.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean DBentry( String query ) {
        try {
            System.out.println("query="+query);
            instance.newConnection();
            sql= dbconn.prepareStatement(query);
            sql.executeUpdate(query);
            dbconn.close();
            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception err ) {
            err.getStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean entry(String itemNum,String price,String fName,String lName,String shipAdd,String cardType, String ccn ) {
        try {
            instance.DBentry("INSERT INTO cs485_lab5.Orders ( `Item Number`, `Price`, 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'ShippingAddress', 'CreditCard', 'CCN') " +  
                                "VALUES ('"+itemNum+"','"+price+"','"+fName+"','"+lName+"','"+shipAdd+"','"+cardType+"',  '"+ccn+"');");    
            return true;
        }
        catch ( Exception err ) {
            err.getStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        //instance.entry("123wdr", "1234.00", "Bill", "Bob", "1234 jon doe street", "Visa", "12345677");
    }
}
```

**ShowParameters.java**

```
package db;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ShowParameters extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String docType =
                "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 " +
                "Transitional//EN\">\n";
        String title = "Reading All Request Parameters";

        out.println(docType +
                "<HTML>\n" +
                "<HEAD><TITLE>" + title + "</TITLE></HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY BGCOLOR=\"#FDF5E6\">\n" +
                "<H1 ALIGN=CENTER>" + title + "</H1>\n" +
                "<TABLE BORDER=1 ALIGN=CENTER>\n" +
                "<TR BGCOLOR=\"#FFAD00\">\n" +
                "<TH>Parameter Name<TH>Parameter Value(s)");

        Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
        while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String paramName = (String)paramNames.nextElement();
            out.print("<TR><TD>" + paramName + "\n<TD>");
            String[] paramValues =
                    request.getParameterValues(paramName);
            if (paramValues.length == 1) {
                String paramValue = paramValues[0];
                if (paramValue.length() == 0)
                    out.println("<I>No Value</I>");
                else
                    out.println(paramValue);
            } else {
                out.println("<UL>");
                for(int i=0; i<paramValues.length; i++) {
                    out.println("<LI>" + paramValues[i]);
                }
                out.println("</UL>");
            }
        }

        out.println("</TABLE>\n</BODY></HTML>");
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("STOP1\n");
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Lab 5</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import="db.*" %>
<body BGCOLOR="#FDF5E6">

<h1 align="center"> Customer Order Form</h1>
<form action="ShowParameters" method="post">
    Item Number: <input type="text" name="itemNum"> <br>
    Price Each: <input value="$" type="text" name="price"> <br>
    <hr>
    First Name: <input type = "text" name = "fname"> <br>
    Last Name: <input type = "text" name = "lname"> <br>
    Shipping Address: <textarea name = "shipadd" style ="resize:none "></textarea> <br>
    Credit Card: <br>
    <input name="creditcard" value ="visa" type="radio">Visa <br>
    <input name="creditcard" value ="mastercard" type="radio">MasterCard <br>
    Credit Card Number: <input name = "ccn" type="text">
    <center><input type="submit" value="Submit Order"></center>
</form>
<%
String itemNum=request.getParameter("itemNum");
String price=request.getParameter("price");
String fName=request.getParameter("fname");
String lName=request.getParameter("lname");
String shipAdd=request.getParameter("shipadd");
String cardType=request.getParameter("creditcard");
String ccn=request.getParameter("ccn");

if (itemNum!= null&&!itemNum.trim().equals("")){
    DBentry DBentry = new DBentry();
    boolean flag=DBentry.entry(itemNum, price, fName, lName, shipAdd, cardType, ccn);
    if(flag){%><script type="text/javascript">alert("Entry Success");</script><%
    }
    else { %><script type="text/javascript">alert("Entry Failure");</script><%}
}

%>
</body>

</html>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Lab5</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: did you define the servlet in web.xml?

Comment: I just added the web.xml.  I don't have a lot of understanding as to the purpose of the web.xml page. I'm also finding that my data isn't submitting to the database anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the servlet mappings to your web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Lab5</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>showParameters</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>db.ShowParameters</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>showParameters</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ShowParameters</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The first tag `<servlet>` and its innards tell Tomcat what class to find the servlet in and gives the servlet a name. The next tag `<servlet-mapping>` identifies the servlet by that name and maps it to a url.

Comment: Ok, that worked.  Thanks for the explanation as well.  Any thoughts as to why the submitted data is not being added to the database?  Do you by chance see an error that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Add servlet mapping in web.xml using

> `<servlet>`

and

> `<servlet-mapping>`

or just add the `@WebServlet` annotation at the top of your servlet.